# Add csv file to HTTP POST

Tags: csv, postman

I want to send a postman HTTP POST. In this request, for key 'fisier', I like to attach a csv file. How this can be done?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnkii.png

Comment: I have a screen shot, but I didn't manage to upload it. I'm trying right now ..

Comment: I understand, the description it's link to my image. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This can be done using

1. Select the `POST` method and type the url
2. In the Body menu header, click on `form-data` check-box
3. In the key-value form that comes,

   3.1 add the key as `fisier`

   3.2 Choose the type as `File` from the dropdown near the key

   3.3 A file chooser button opens, click it, borwse the file and upload it

   3.4 Click on Send method to send the request

[image: Illustration for the steps]